# Swapping two elements x and y positions

Tags: javascript, swap

I am trying to swap two images .x and .y positions. The method I am using fails because I think once I do first swap they point to same positions or something, seems only one moves to new position hope this makes sense.

```
theSequence[i].onClick = function(e){
           firstObject.push(this);

            if(firstObject.length == 2){
              firstObject[0].x = firstObject[1].x;
              firstObject[0].y = firstObject[1].y;
              firstObject[1].x = firstObject[0].x;
              firstObject[1].y= firstObject[0].y;
            }
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JS and absolutely nothing with easeljs. This is somewhat of a programming 101 question.

Comment: @Imp: The question uses JS syntax and if another language was specified (such as Python) then you would solve this differently. So the language does have relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use temp variable:

```
if(firstObject.length == 2)
{
    tempX = firstObject[0].x;
    tempY = firstObject[0].y;
    firstObject[0].x = firstObject[1].x;
    firstObject[0].y = firstObject[1].y;
    firstObject[1].x = tempX;
    firstObject[1].y= tempY;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with your logic.

When you do:

```
firstObject[0].x = firstObject[1].x;
firstObject[0].y = firstObject[1].y;
```

Both images will have the same `x` and `y` coords. So, when you do:

```
firstObject[1].x = firstObject[0].x;
firstObject[1].y= firstObject[0].y;
```

It's redundant. You need to store the `x` and `y` of your `firstObject[0]` in variables before changing them and then assign the value of those variables to `firstObject[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid temp variable in ECMAscript you can use:

```
[a, b] = [b, a];
```

(like in python) or use this hack:

```
a = -(b = (a += b) - b) + a;
```

[source](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=265)